# What's the monitor-sensor file in the /bin folder of ubuntu? What does it do?

Tags: drivers, usb, filesystem, 19.10

0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 1fg5 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
the file on sublime text looks like this. can anyone tell me what is this file used for in computer system??

Comment: have you not seen the file extension name and then Google about that file extension?

Comment: it's not much of a help.

Comment: good.. atleast you tried it. I dont have 19.10 installed rite now. but as the name suggests.. it could be of temperature sensor or could be motion/ rotation sensor kind of thing. what is the exact location of this file in 19.10?

Comment: /bin/monitpr-sensor... in root directory

Answer (score 0):

based on the file `/bin/monitor-sensor` you can simply search for package details

for Example: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=eoan&section=all&arch=any&keywords=monitor-sensor&searchon=contents

the Package is `iio-sensor-proxy (2.8-0ubuntu1)`

then you can do `apt show iiiio-sensor-proxy`

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ apt show iio-sensor-proxy
Package: iio-sensor-proxy
Version: 2.8-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Ritesh Raj Sarraf <rrs@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 167 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.39.90), libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 146), systemd
Homepage: https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy
Task: ubuntu-desktop-minimal, ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-minimal-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, kubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-video, ubuntustudio-publishing, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop
Supported: 9m
Download-Size: 35.5 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
Description: IIO sensors to D-Bus proxy
 Industrial I/O subsystem is intended to provide support for devices
 that in some sense are analog to digital or digital to analog convertors
 .
 Devices that fall into this category are:
  * ADCs
  * Accelerometers
  * Gyros
  * IMUs
  * Capacitance to Digital Converters (CDCs)
  * Pressure Sensors
  * Color, Light and Proximity Sensors
  * Temperature Sensors
  * Magnetometers
  * DACs
  * DDS (Direct Digital Synthesis)
  * PLLs (Phase Locked Loops)
  * Variable/Programmable Gain Amplifiers (VGA, PGA)
 .
 Many ultrabooks ship with some of these devices. iio-sensor-proxy is
 intended to serve as a proxy, providing access to these devices through
 a D-Bus interface

pratap@i7-4770:~$
```